# How to add cms page on magento default footer links?

Tags: magento2, footer

I want to move Customer loyalty program from right side of footer. please see below image?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you achieve this using default.xml

```
 <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current"  name="name-of-your-link" after="frequently-asked-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Loyalty Program</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path of your cms page</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

( you have to take a correct name of frequently asked question link and then put inside after attribute )

Comment: *"path of your cms page"* without any preceding slash... hopefully will save someone a few minutes of pain....